# Swift - If time ago is more then x minutes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a date like this:

`let date = Date()`

Lets say that the date is 12.08.2021 14:40. I want to check and do stuff if there is more then 25 minutes past that date. How can I do this?

Comment: `timeIntervalSinceNow` and there are 25*60 seconds in 25 minutes

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407937-timeintervalsincenow) and measure the difference (in seconds)

```
let previousDate = Date().advanced(by: -1000)
print("previous: \(previousDate)")

if -previousDate.timeIntervalSinceNow > 25 * 60 {
    print("past 25 minutes")
} else {
    print("not past 25 minutes")
}
```

This example is relative, so will always print `"not past 25 minutes"` - however `previousDate` would be the actual previous date.

Comment: The `print` gives me totally wrong time. It says `2021-08-12 22:29:04` but my time at the same time is `2021-08-13 00:45:50`. Why is that?

Comment: @CarolineSweden What value is giving the wrong date?

Comment: `print("previous: \(previousDate)")` gives me wrong.

Comment: So when using your code, it always returns `print("past 25 minutes")`

Comment: @CarolineSweden Given the times you said in the previous comment, the gap between that is more than 25 minutes so it makes sense. If you try this example in the answer, using the relative times, it should always give you the same result. Change the `-1000` to `-10000` and you should see it changes to `"past 25 minutes"`.

Comment: It only works with iOS 13 and above.

Answer (score 0):

The below function will allow you to check if the elapsed time since a previous date is more than a specific number of minutes.

```
func intervalSince(_ previous: Date, isMoreThan minutes: Int) -> Bool {
   return Date() > previous.advanced(by: Double(minutes) * 60.0)
}
```

Note: This method only works with iOS 13 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function. you use `date.timeAgoSince()`. This confirms how many minutes ago your variable was.

```swift
  extension Date {
        func timeAgoSince() -> String {
        
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let now = Date().datePickerToString().stringToDate()
            let unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year]
            let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(unitFlags, from: self, to: now, options: [])

            if let minute = components.minute, minute >= 1 {
                return "past \(minute) minutes"
            }

            return "now"
}
```